# Broken Dev-C++ Install in Windows 7 User Account

Tags: windows-7, installation, c++, ide

On Windows 7, I'm upgrading from Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 to 5.11.

First I uninstalled the old version, then install 5.11. Running it then works fine under an Administrator account, but trying to run it in my standard User account things are broken and missing. Here are a few examples.

Under File > New > Project wizard, running in the Admin account has several tabs and options, while the User account is missing all of those:

[image: New Project: Admin]

[image: New Project: User]

Under Tools > Compiler > Options, the Admin account sees a half-dozen meaningful compilation profiles, while the User sees two broken, malformed profiles:

[image: Compiler Options, Admin]

[image: Compiler Options, User]

Likewise, many other parts of the IDE are broken when running from the User account, e.g., (1) Help cannot be accessed, (2) daily Tips are not found, (3) many language-package errors result from selecting an associated file (.H, .C., .CPP, etc.) from Windows, (4) many interface widgets have broken text (such as the `<desc>` in the first example above), etc. All of these items works as expected and usefully when run from the Admin account.

Note that this program does not use the system path for anything. The installer does not modify the path in any way, and even without any modifications, everything works fine in the Admin account. Directories for compiling are stored internally to the program (visible in the example above). The broken "default" compiler profile in the User account seems like a possibly appropriate fallback for the old v.4.9.9.2, listing directories used in that version, but do not exist in 5.11. One commenter has been confused by this, because that's actually the first thing the IDE complains about on startup in User (directories in the profile settings that do not actually exist). I've removed that as the initial example here for clarity. But the problems are far more widespread and fundamental than just the compiler directories (e.g., interface, wizard, languages, help, are all broken).

I've tried installing the IDE both in the User and the Administrator account, but the behavior (from the User account) is the same in either case. I've rebooted between installations and the problems persist. I'll note that the install procedure for the prior version has a "do you want to install this for all users?" question (I'd install that in Administrator and use it in User just fine), but this one never presents such an option.

I feel like I'm missing something very simple in my install process for Dev-C++ 5.11, what is it?

Comment: Directories C:\Dev-Cpp\bin, C:\Dev-Cpp\lib, C:\Dev-Cpp\include are indeed on my path... although (as the message box says) they don't actually exist.

Comment: @Ramhound: I tried that, but it doesn't help. See "Edit" in the question above; I'm pretty sure the problem is more fundamental than just those directories being complained about in respect to the compiler. Lots of other stuff is broken in the User account besides that; and the Admin account runs everything fine both with and without Path changes.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'll highlight again that the problems are much deeper than just the compiler directories. Yes, I have removed the directories from path, rebooted, and reinstalled. The installer does not add anything to the path, and the IDE works fine in the Admin account. I believe those directories were added to the path by me in the past for command-line compilation. Dev-C++ keeps an internal settings list of needed compiler directories, and does not seem to use the path for that.

Comment: For completion sake I've added all the compiler directories listed in the v5.11 internal settings to the path, confirmed, rebooted... and as expected the behavior is still the same.

Comment: @Ramhound: The path is the same in both environments. This program does not use the path in any way.

Comment: "This program does not use the path in any way." - Yes; It actually does. This application is a C++ development tool with the ability to compile code, which means those directories, are where the GCC C++ compiler is.  What makes you think those directories, the program is complaining about, are not being used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105879/discussion-between-ramhound-and-daniel-r-collins).

Comment: I've edited the question to focus on the more fundamental issues (not just the initial compiler directories complaint), and to highlight that the program does not use the system path in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was a lingering initialization file, **devcpp.ini**, hidden in the directory **C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Dev-Cpp**, which persisted on unistallation of the old program, and was apparently referenced but not properly utilized by the new program (which itself puts its own .ini in a different folder).

After uninstalling the old program and deleting this user configuration directory, the new program could install and run correctly.